# Select and fill between two empty rows

Tags: vba, excel

I'm super new to Macros and VBA in general. I searched online everywhere to find a solution to my problem but I couldn't find any. I have the following data in this format:

```
A    B    C
    ...   Text1
    ...   Text1
    ...   Text1
    ...   Text1
--- empty row
    ...   Text2
    ...   Text2
    ...   Text2
--- empty row
    ...   Text3
    ...   Text3
--- empty row
```

The A column is all empty. And I want to fill the A like this:

```
    A    B    C
    1   ...   Text1
    2   ...   Text1
    3   ...   Text1
    4   ...   Text1
--- empty row
    1   ...   Text2
    2   ...   Text2
    3   ...   Text2
--- empty row
    1   ...   Text3
    2   ...   Text3
--- empty row
```

Basically, start counting from 1-x until the value in C changes to empty row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code if you need to count filled cells in "C" row.

```
dim counter as integer
counter=1
For i=1 to activesheet.usedrange.rows.count
if not Range("C" & i).value="" Then
    Range("A" & i).value=counter
    counter=counter+1
else
    counter=1
end if
next i
```

Comment: Okay, does this work for the finding the range of filled cells in the C row?

Comment: Yes. It will update information in sheet exactly like in you'r example.
You can place it between sub...end sub in sheet code page or in any module

Answer (score 0):

Type this formula into A2 cell and drag down:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",IF(OR(ROW(C1)=1,ISBLANK(C1)),1,A1+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use special cells

```html
Sub Test()
    Dim myAreas     As Areas
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim x           As Long
    
    Set myAreas = Columns("C").SpecialCells(2).Areas
    
    For i = myAreas.Count To 1 Step -1
        For x = 1 To myAreas(i).Count
            myAreas(i)(x).Offset(, -2).Value = x
        Next x
    Next i
End Sub
```